# Subtração entre 2 campos

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer com que meu campo Total Final(tf) mostre o resultado da subtração de outros 2 campos, porem não estou sabendo como fazer calcular, alguém saberia me dizer como faço isso?

```js
 <script>
  function calcular() {
     var g1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('g1').value);
      var g2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('g2').value);
     document.getElementById('gresult').innerHTML = g1 + g2;
     document.getElementById('tg').innerHTML = g1 + g2;
    var d1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('d1').value);
      var d2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('d2').value);
       document.getElementById('dresult').innerHTML = d1 + d2;
     document.getElementById('td').innerHTML = d1 + d2;
    var tg = parseInt(document.getElementById('tg').value);
    var td = parseInt(document.getElementById('td').value);
     document.getElementById('tf').innerHTML = tg - td;
   }
  </script>
```

```html
<body>
  <h1> Fluxo de caixa </h1>

  <table border=1>
  <tr bgcolor="lightgreen">
   <th colspan = "3"> Ganhos (G) </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th> Data </th>
   <th> Descrição </th>
   <th> Valor </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type = "date"></td>
   <td><input type = "text"></td>
   <td><input type = "text" id="g1" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type = "date"></td>
   <td><input type = "text"></td>
   <td><input type = "text" id="g2" value="" onblur="calcular()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th colspan = "2" bgcolor="lightgreen"> Total </th>
   <td id="gresult"><input></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
<br><br><br><br>
  <table border=1>
  <tr bgcolor="red">
   <th colspan = "3"> Despesas (D) </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th> Data </th>
   <th> Descrição </th>
   <th> Valor </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type = "date"></td>
   <td><input type = "text"></td>
   <td><input type = "text" id="d1" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type = "date"></td>
   <td><input type = "text"></td>
   <td><input type = "text" id="d2" value="" onblur="calcular()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th colspan = "2" bgcolor="red"> Total </th>
   <td id="dresult"><input></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
<br><br><br><br>
  <table border=1>
  <tr>
   <th colspan = "2" bgcolor="lightblue"> Resumo </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td bgcolor="lightgreen"> Ganhos (G) </td>
   <td id="tg"><input type = "text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td bgcolor="red"> Despesas (D) </td>
   <td id="td"><input type = "text" onblur="calcular()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td bgcolor="lightblue"> Total Final </td>
   <td id="tf"><input></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 </body
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O **id="tg"** está na **tag td** e não na **tag input**. Mas é melhor fazer o cálculo na variável ao invés de fazer pelo innerHTML.

**Segue o código corrigido:**

```
function calcular() {
      var g1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('g1').value);
      var g2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('g2').value);
      var tg = g1 + g2;
      document.getElementById('gresult').innerHTML = tg;
      document.getElementById('tg').innerHTML = tg;
      var d1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('d1').value);
      var d2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('d2').value);
      var td = d1 + d2;
      document.getElementById('dresult').innerHTML = td;
      document.getElementById('td').innerHTML = td;
      document.getElementById('tf').innerHTML = tg - td;
 }
```

Outras dicas:

1. Dar nomes mais explicativos para as variáveis e para os Ids;
2. Utilizar **const** ao invés de **var** para variáveis que não irão mudar de valor;
3. Separar cada funcionalidade em uma função. Exemplo: calcularGanhos, calcularDespesas, etc...

**Ficaria assim com as mudanças:**

```
function calcular() {
       const ganhos = calcularGanhos();
       const despesas = calcularDespesas();

       document.getElementById('gresult').innerHTML = ganhos;
       document.getElementById('tg').innerHTML = ganhos;

       document.getElementById('dresult').innerHTML = despesas;
       document.getElementById('td').innerHTML = despesas;

       document.getElementById('tf').innerHTML = ganhos - despesas;
}

function calcularGanhos() {
  const ganhos = [
    +document.getElementById('g1').value,
    +document.getElementById('g2').value,
  ];
  return somatorio(ganhos);
}

function calcularDespesas() {
  const despesas = [
    +document.getElementById('d1').value,
    +document.getElementById('d2').value,
  ];
  return somatorio(despesas);
}

function somatorio(valores) {
  return valores.reduce((acumulador, valorCorrente) => acumulador + valorCorrente);
}
```

O que pode ser visto neste código:

1. Desta forma cada método tem a responsabilidade de fazer cada coisa;
2. O **+** é uma abreviação do **parseInt**;
3. Com as variáveis mais legíveis dá para saber o que cada um está fazendo;
4. Com o **reduce**, é possível somar mais do que dois valores, caso coloques mais;
5. Esse código pode diminuir ainda mais com ajuda de frameworks ou bibliotecas JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está tentando capturar o `value` do `tg` e `td`, que são elementos do tipo `<td>`, ou seja, `HTMLTableCellElement`.

Essa classe não possui `value`, note que você mesmo  utiliza `document.getElementById('tg').innerHTML = g1 + g2` para atribuir o resultado a essa célula, você está atribuindo o resultado a propriedade `innerHTML`, não `value`.

Então você poderia recuperar esse valor através da propriedade `innerHTML`:

```
var tg = parseInt(document.getElementById('tg').innerHTML);
var td = parseInt(document.getElementById('td').innerHTML);
document.getElementById('tf').innerHTML = tg - td;
```

Mas na minha opinião não tem pra que fazer isso, você já tem os valores de `g1`, `g2`, `d1` e `d2`, ao invés de fazer uma query no seu documento, e o parse desses html, seria muito mais sensato utilizar os valores que você já tem em mão:

```
function calcular() {
    var g1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('g1').value);
    var g2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('g2').value);
    document.getElementById('gresult').innerHTML = g1 + g2;
    document.getElementById('tg').innerHTML = g1 + g2;

    var d1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('d1').value);
    var d2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('d2').value);
    document.getElementById('dresult').innerHTML = d1 + d2;
    document.getElementById('td').innerHTML = d1 + d2;

    document.getElementById('tf').innerHTML = (g1 + g2) - (d1 + d2);
}
```